# Tensorflow seq2seq Model, loss value is good, but prediction is false

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0, loss-function, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

I'm trying to train a Seq2Seq model. It should translate sentences from a source_vocabulary to sentences in a target_vocabulary.

The loss value is 0.28, but the network doesn't predict words from the target-vocabulary. Instead the predictions of the network are negative values. I'm not sure, if something in the code is false or if the vocabulary is too big or if I didn't trained enough. I trained with a part of the dataset with about 270 000 sentences. Even if the loss value decreases, I don't know if the network is learning something.

```py
def encDecEmb():
    batch_size = 32
    seq_length = 40
    vocab_size = 289415
    epochs = 10
    embedding_size = 300
    hidden_units = 20
    learning_rate = 0.001

    #shape = batch_size, seq_length
    encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.int32, shape=(None, None), name='encoder_inputs')
    decoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.int32, shape=(None, None), name='decoder_inputs')

    sequence_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='sequence_length')

    # Embedding
    embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [vocab_size, embedding_size])
    encoder_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, encoder_inputs)
    decoder_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, decoder_inputs)

    # Encoder
    encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_units)
    encoder_outputs, encoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        encoder_cell, encoder_embedding, dtype=tf.float32)

    projection_layer = Dense(vocab_size, use_bias=False)
    helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(decoder_embedding,
                                               sequence_length=sequence_length)

    # Decoder
    decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_units)
    decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
        cell=decoder_cell, initial_state=encoder_final_state, helper=helper,
        output_layer=projection_layer)

    decoder_outputs, _final_state, _final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
        decoder)

    logits = decoder_outputs.rnn_output
    training_logits = tf.identity(decoder_outputs.rnn_output, name='logits')
    target_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size, seq_length))

    weight_mask = tf.sequence_mask([i for i in range(
        batch_size)], seq_length, dtype=tf.float32, name="weight_mask")

    # loss
    loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(
        logits=training_logits, targets=decoder_inputs, weights=weight_mask)

    #AdamOptimizer, Gradientclipping
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
    capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var)
                        for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
    train_opt = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)

    # read files
    x = readCSV_to_int("./xTest.csv")
    y = readCSV_to_int("./yTest.csv")

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for batch, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(get_batches(x, y, batch_size)):
            _, loss_value = sess.run([train_opt, loss],
                                     feed_dict={encoder_inputs: inputs, decoder_inputs: targets, target_labels: targets,
                                                sequence_length: [len(inputs[0])] * batch_size})
            print('Epoch{:>3}  Batch {:>4}/{}  Loss {:>6.4f}'.format(epoch, batch, (len(x) // batch_size),
                                                                     loss_value))

    saver.save(sess, './model_on_testset')
    print("Model Trained and Saved")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly O.K. that the logits are negative numbers, they are outputs of the network before normalizing by softmax, i.e., the numbers get exponentiated (and thus become small positive numbers) before they are normalized.

The architecture of your choice: vanilla sequence-to-sequence model is not the easiest one to train. Given you have only a limited number of training data (270k) I would use:

1. A bidirectional encoder; and
2. A decoder with the attention mechanism.

Attention simplifies the gradient flow from the decoder (where the actual loss computations happen) to the decoder as the gradients do not flow only via the encoder final state, but through attention to all encoder states.

There are also other things that influence the performance: e.g. how you segment your data (whether you use words or subwords) and how big your vocabulary you use.

Anyway, the best way how to find out if your model is learning something is to try to decode target sentences from the model.